# SQL - ¿cuál es el propósito de operar fechas como números?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto donde tengo que adaptar un código existente; sin embargo, no comprendo el objetivo de esta consulta:

```
SELECT <some columns>
FROM sample_table AS M
WHERE YEAR(@BETWEEN_DATE) * 365 + MONTH(@BETWEEN_DATE) * 30 + DAY(@BETWEEN_DATE)
BETWEEN (
       YEAR(M.STARTINGDATE) * 365 + MONTH(M.STARTINGDATE) * 
       30 + DAY(M.STARTINGDATE)
   )
   AND 
   CASE 
        WHEN M.ENDINGDATE IS NULL THEN (
                 YEAR('99990101') * 365 + MONTH('99990101') * 30 + DAY('19000101')
             )
        ELSE (
                 YEAR(M.ENDINGDATE) * 365 + MONTH(M.ENDINGDATE)
                 * 30 + DAY(M.ENDINGDATE)
             )
   END
```

De la consulta anterior, entiendo que la fecha del parámetro `@BETWEEN_DATE` la convierte a números, pero, esa lógica es enredada.

> Lo que intuyo es que el parámetro `@BETWEEN_DATE` lo convierte a número para validar que las fechas de inicio `M.STARTINGDATE` y fin `M.ENDINGDATE` estén entre el rango. Estas fechas de inicio y fin las operaron así para agregarle un año al valor almacenado en `M.STARTINGDATE` y `M.ENDINGDATE`, pero, no tengo la certeza. *Además, este proyecto ha pasado por muchas personas, así que no tengo cómo apoyarme en ese sentido*.

El resultado "en caso de que el parámetro `@BETWEEN_DATE` sea `2020-06-18 00:00:00.000`", los valores de año, mes y día serían así:

```
DECLARE @BETWEEN_DATE DATETIME = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE);
SELECT @BETWEEN_DATE AS FECHA, YEAR(@BETWEEN_DATE) * 365 + MONTH(@BETWEEN_DATE) * 30 + DAY(@BETWEEN_DATE) AS RESULTADO_NUMERICO, 
YEAR(@BETWEEN_DATE) * 365 AS ANIO,
MONTH(@BETWEEN_DATE) * 30 AS MES, 
DAY(@BETWEEN_DATE) AS DIA;

Año: 737300
Mes: 180
Día: 18
```

Quiero modificar la consulta para que sea mas simple de adaptar al proyecto que tengo asignado.

Comment: Es un supuesto en el que operar con números es más sencillo pero, posiblemente, descarta las optimizaciones que hayan hecho en el motor de BD para operar con fechas. Igual se están haciendo varios `casting` para esta estrategia, así que la mejora de esta estrategia es relativa y sí dificulta el mantenimiento del código (lo que le sube el costo a largo plazo).

Answer (score 3):

A priori no aporta nada, y puede penalizar en caso de disponer de algún tipo de índice, pero como no hay nada mejor que comprobarlo con datos.

Creamos una tabla con 500.000 filas, y la llenamos de datos, para ver el comportamiento. He incluido también dos columnas datetime, por si fuera necesario. De momento no se utilizarán.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.EjFechas (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), STARTDATE DATE, ENDDATE DATE, STARDATETIME DATETIME, ENDDATETIME DATETIME);
GO
;WITH R AS 
(
    SELECT 1 AS N FROM  SYS.objects C
        CROSS JOIN SYS.objects D
        CROSS JOIN SYS.OBJECTS E
), R2 AS (
    SELECT TOP(500000) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS ROW
    FROM R
)
INSERT INTO dbo.EjFechas (STARTDATE, ENDDATE, STARDATETIME, ENDDATETIME)
SELECT 
      dateadd(day,(r2.ROW/100),'20200101') as StartDate
    , dateadd(day,((r2.ROW/100)+30),'20200101') as EndDate
    , dateadd(hour,(r2.ROW),'20200101') as StartDateTime
    , dateadd(hour,((r2.ROW+48)),'20200101') as EndDate
FROM r2;
go
```

Para no beneficiarnos del comportamiento de los planes en cache y de los datos que ya existen en memoria, previo a cada consulta aplicamos dbcc freeproccache y dbbcc dropcleanbuffers.

***Nota***: Solo utilizar en servidores de desarrollo, nunca en producción.

Además cada consulta irá precedida de Set statistics time, io para saber lo que le conlleva al motor ejecutar las mismas.

**Consulta 1.** (Adaptados los nombres de columnas al ejemplo)

```
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;
GO
set statistics time, io on;
DECLARE @BETWEEN_DATE DATETIME = GETDATE();
SELECT *
FROM dbo.EjFechas AS M
WHERE YEAR(@BETWEEN_DATE) * 365 + MONTH(@BETWEEN_DATE) * 30 + DAY(@BETWEEN_DATE)
BETWEEN (
       YEAR(M.STARTDATE) * 365 + MONTH(M.STARTDATE) * 
       30 + DAY(M.STARTDATE)
   )
   AND 
   CASE 
        WHEN M.ENDDATE IS NULL THEN (
                 YEAR('99990101') * 365 + MONTH('99990101') * 30 + DAY('19000101')
             )
        ELSE (
                 YEAR(M.ENDDATE) * 365 + MONTH(M.ENDDATE)
                 * 30 + DAY(M.ENDDATE)
             )
   END
set statistics time, io off;
GO
```

Resultados:

```
(3100 filas afectadas)
Tabla "EjFechas". Número de examen 1, lecturas lógicas 2165, lecturas físicas 0, lecturas de servidor de páginas 0, lecturas anticipadas 2158, lecturas anticipadas de servidor de páginas 0, lecturas lógicas de línea de negocio 0, lecturas físicas de línea de negocio 0, lecturas de servidor de páginas de línea de negocio 0, lecturas anticipadas de línea de negocio 0, lecturas anticipadas de servidor de páginas de línea de negocio 0.

 Tiempos de ejecución de SQL Server:
   Tiempo de CPU = 203 ms, tiempo transcurrido = 484 ms.
```

**Consulta 2** Utilizando Fechas (cast as date)

```
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;
GO

SET STATISTICS TIME, IO ON;
DECLARE @BETWEEN_DATE DATE =  CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE);

SELECT *
       FROM dbo.EjFechas AS M
       WHERE @BETWEEN_DATE >= M.STARTDATE and
             @BETWEEN_DATE <= M.ENDDATE

SET STATISTICS TIME, IO OFF;
```

Resultados:

```
(3100 filas afectadas)
Tabla "EjFechas". Número de examen 1, lecturas lógicas 2165, lecturas físicas 0, lecturas de servidor de páginas 0, lecturas anticipadas 2158, lecturas anticipadas de servidor de páginas 0, lecturas lógicas de línea de negocio 0, lecturas físicas de línea de negocio 0, lecturas de servidor de páginas de línea de negocio 0, lecturas anticipadas de línea de negocio 0, lecturas anticipadas de servidor de páginas de línea de negocio 0.

 Tiempos de ejecución de SQL Server:
   Tiempo de CPU = 47 ms, tiempo transcurrido = 310 ms.
```

Ahora vamos a ver el plan de ejecución que hace realmente.

[image: Plan de ejecución]

El mismo me indica que la consulta es mejorable, que hay un indice a aplicar.

Voy a recoger su sugerencia, y voy a crear ese índice, tal cuál lo plantea. (No es una buena opción aplicar los índices sin analizarlos, pero para el ejemplo es perfecta).

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_FECHAS ON [dbo].[EjFechas] 
([STARTDATE],[ENDDATE])
INCLUDE ([ID],[STARDATETIME],[ENDDATETIME])
```

Con el índice creado, realizo ambas consultas de nuevo. Pero ahora con ambos planes de ejecución marcados.

**Consulta 1**

```
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;
GO
set statistics time, io on;
DECLARE @BETWEEN_DATE DATETIME = GETDATE();
SELECT *
FROM dbo.EjFechas AS M
WHERE YEAR(@BETWEEN_DATE) * 365 + MONTH(@BETWEEN_DATE) * 30 + DAY(@BETWEEN_DATE)
BETWEEN (
       YEAR(M.STARTDATE) * 365 + MONTH(M.STARTDATE) * 
       30 + DAY(M.STARTDATE)
   )
   AND 
   CASE 
        WHEN M.ENDDATE IS NULL THEN (
                 YEAR('99990101') * 365 + MONTH('99990101') * 30 + DAY('19000101')
             )
        ELSE (
                 YEAR(M.ENDDATE) * 365 + MONTH(M.ENDDATE)
                 * 30 + DAY(M.ENDDATE)
             )
   END
set statistics time, io off;
GO
```

Resultado:

```
(3100 filas afectadas)
Tabla "EjFechas". Número de examen 1, lecturas lógicas 2165, lecturas físicas 339, lecturas de servidor de páginas 0, lecturas anticipadas 2165, lecturas anticipadas de servidor de páginas 0, lecturas lógicas de línea de negocio 0, lecturas físicas de línea de negocio 0, lecturas de servidor de páginas de línea de negocio 0, lecturas anticipadas de línea de negocio 0, lecturas anticipadas de servidor de páginas de línea de negocio 0.

(1 fila afectada)

 Tiempos de ejecución de SQL Server:
   Tiempo de CPU = 188 ms, tiempo transcurrido = 2535 ms.
```

Plan de ejecución:

[image: Plan de ejecución consulta 1]

La query realiza una lectura de la tabla completa para obtener resultados.

**Consulta 2**

```
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;
GO

SET STATISTICS TIME, IO ON;
DECLARE @BETWEEN_DATE DATE = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE);

SELECT *
       FROM dbo.EjFechas AS M
       WHERE @BETWEEN_DATE  >= M.STARTDATE and
             @BETWEEN_DATE <= M.ENDDATE

SET STATISTICS TIME, IO OFF;
```

Resultados

```
(3100 filas afectadas)
Tabla "EjFechas". Número de examen 1, lecturas lógicas 2165, lecturas físicas 0, lecturas de servidor de páginas 0, lecturas anticipadas 2158, lecturas anticipadas de servidor de páginas 0, lecturas lógicas de línea de negocio 0, lecturas físicas de línea de negocio 0, lecturas de servidor de páginas de línea de negocio 0, lecturas anticipadas de línea de negocio 0, lecturas anticipadas de servidor de páginas de línea de negocio 0.

(1 fila afectada)

 Tiempos de ejecución de SQL Server:
   Tiempo de CPU = 46 ms, tiempo transcurrido = 374 ms.
```

Plan de ejecución

[image: Plan ejecución consulta 2]

Ahora la query se beneficia del index, cosa que la anterior no puede.

El concepto importante de esto es que ese tipo de cálculos en el where hacen que las mismas no se puedan beneficiar de ningún tipo de índice, cosa que de otro modo pudiera ser. **(SARGABLE)**

[Borrar cache y planes](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/06/07/borrar-la-cache-y-planes-de-ejecucion-para-pruebas/)

[Querys Sargable](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-use-sargable-expressions-in-t-sql-queries-performance-advantages-and-examples/)

Answer (score 0):

El que lo programó no quería complicarse la vida. Transforma la fecha a número porque más tarde va a comprobar si esta fecha es menor que una fecha tope, y comprobar si un número es menor que otro es más sencillo que hacer comprobaciones campo a campo.

Es como comparar si una hora (dentro de un mismo día) es mayor o menor que otra. Es trivial si lo transformas todo a segundos.

En cierto sentido, lo que el programador hizo es pasar todo a días, para comparar si el número de días de la fecha de la variable es menor que la fecha límite en días.

Comment: ¿pero no sería mas sencillo comparar si la fecha es mayor a otra? - por que, con mi pregunta intento entender qué obtiene por ejemplo este valor: `YEAR(M.ENDINGDATE) * 365 + MONTH(M.ENDINGDATE) * 30 + DAY(M.ENDINGDATE)` - intenté convertir este valor y dice que no es correcto. Es posible que yo no lo esté haciendo bien, pero, si ese ejemplo puede convertirse en fecha, ¿qué valor obtendría?

Comment: Obtendrías (si el cálculo estuviese bien hecho) el número de día contando desde el año cero. Por ejemplo, hoy 19 de junio de 2020 sería el día 2019 * 365 + 5 * 30 + 19 = 737104, y mañana será el día 737105. Por supuesto yo tampoco lo haría así. El programador no sabía manejar bien las fechas, o no quería por algún motivo. Pero es cierto que hay fallas en ese cálculo, ya que no tiene en cuenta años bisiestos, meses de 31 días, etc. Pero incluso sin tener esto en cuenta, su fórmula está mal. Debería ser, al menos `YEAR(M.ENDINGDATE-1) * 365 + MONTH(M.ENDINGDATE-1) * 30 + DAY(M.ENDINGDATE)`.

Answer (score 0):

yo llevo ya bastante tiempo trabajando con SQL server y con volúmenes grandes de registros pero como dice tu pregunta ¿cuál es el propósito de operar fechas como números? Te explico. Cuando tu consultas volúmenes grandes de información con consultas como:

```
select * from tabla where fecha >= '2020-01-01' and fecha <= '2020-06-18'
```

no es factible (con volúmenes grandes) pues las consultas tardan demasiado y si estas ejecutando desde alguna aplicación el connection timeout puede agotarse, para esto en algunos casos se guarda la fecha en formato numérico (SQL server tiene la opcion de convertir la fecha con la siguiente consulta: `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 112)`). Ahora volviendo a tu query lo veo más largo el estar transformando y consultando por día, mes, año. Espero haberte despejado algunas dudas.

Comment: En este caso: `YEAR(M.ENDINGDATE) * 365 + MONTH(M.ENDINGDATE) * 30 + DAY(M.ENDINGDATE)` - intenté convertir este valor y dice que no es correcto. Es posible que yo no lo esté haciendo bien, pero, si ese ejemplo puede convertirse en fecha, ¿qué valor obtendría? - estoy pensando cambiar la lógica de arriba porque honestamente para lo que estoy haciendo no lo puedo dejar igual - es complejo el mantenimiento y quiero dejarlo mas claro.